# What MySQL permissions do I need to provide/remove to prevent Rails' db:reset?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My goal is disable the option for users to call `rake db:reset` on a production machine.

Is there a way to do this via MySQL user permissions (prevent users from making destructive queries)? Is there a way to limit tasks to administrative accounts only? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to remove the [DROP privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop) from your Rails database user.

Keep in mind that the `DROP` privilege is required too when you want to want to drop a table.

That said: Removing the `DROP` privilege will cost you the possibility to run `drop_table` in migration. That might not be an option or it might actually be a good thing - that depends on your requirements.

Comment: You can always use the Rails `DATABASE_URL` env var to connect to the database as a more privileged user for performing migrations.

Comment: I'll confirm this answer once I test it out; thanks for the response!